# An error occurred while getting access_token with the authorization code

Tags: yammer

I followed the instruction described in yammer developer website, first I use client id to get authentication code after the user log in ,and I successfully got the authorization code,but when I used the code to get access token ,I got a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Yammer changed things and didn't update their docs.

The URL `https://www.yammer.com/oauth2/access_token.json` is still valid, however it must be accessed with a POST request instead of a GET request.

Comment: This change was reverted so that apps using GETs were unblocked. Everything should be OK again now.